# Getting error : IndexError: list index out of range'

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to code for tkinter. This is the code. It is verifiable. You can just put any number to verify this.

```
import tkinter as tk


rectangle_values = []
rectangle_number = []
temp_recta = []
temp_rectn = []
rcta = []
rctn = []
area_var = 0
minw = 0
maxw = 0
minl = 0
maxl = 0
are_a = 0
comp = 0
h = 0

def open_window(rect, mnw,mxw,mnl,mxl):
    window.title('Rectangles')
    global minw
    global maxw
    global minl
    global maxl
    global are_a
    global comp
    global h
    global rectangle_values
    global rectangle_number



    minw = mnw
    maxw = mxw
    minl = mnl
    maxl = mxl
    comp = rect
    x, y, z, j = 400, 405, 405, 1

    l9 = tk.Label(canvas, text="각 Component 입력 정보", font= "calibri 14 bold", bg="white")
    canvas.create_window(30,345, window=l9, anchor=tk.NW)

    l10 = tk.Label(canvas, text="CW", font= "calibri 14", bg="white")
    canvas.create_window(200,370, window=l10, anchor=tk.NW)

    l11 = tk.Label(canvas, text="CH", font= "calibri 14", bg="white")
    canvas.create_window(335,370, window=l11, anchor=tk.NW)    

    l12 = tk.Label(canvas, text="공급사 모재 면적 정보", font= "calibri 14 bold", bg="white")
    canvas.create_window(460,350, window=l12, anchor=tk.NW) 

    l12 = tk.Label(canvas, text="Area", font= "calibri 14", bg="white")
    canvas.create_window(470,380, window=l12, anchor=tk.NW)

    poscoimg3 = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/sel/Desktop/poscoimg3.png")
    canvas.create_image(700,360, image=poscoimg3, anchor=tk.NW)
    canvas.poscoimg3 = poscoimg3

    area_var = tk.DoubleVar()
    entry_area_number = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=area_var)
    canvas.create_window(590,395, window=entry_area_number)





    for i in range(0, rect * 2):         
        if (i % 2) == 0: 
            l1 = tk.Label(canvas, text="Component %d" %(j), font= "calibri 13", bg="white")
            canvas.create_window(30, x, window=l1, anchor=tk.NW)
            rectangle_values.append(tk.StringVar())
            j +=1
            x +=30

            en = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=rectangle_values[i])
            canvas.create_window(150, y, window=en, anchor=tk.NW)
            y +=30

        if (i % 2) != 0:
            rectangle_values.append(tk.StringVar())            
            en = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=rectangle_values[i])
            canvas.create_window(285, z, window=en, anchor=tk.NW)
            z +=30
    h=y       

    #for j in range(0, rect):
        #rectangle_number.append(tk.StringVar())            
        #en = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=rectangle_number[j])
        #canvas.create_window(400, f, window=en, anchor=tk.NW)
        #f +=20

    proceed_button = tk.Button(canvas, text="Run",font= "calibri 13", command=lambda: first_step(area_var.get()))
    canvas.create_window(470, 420, window=proceed_button, anchor=tk.NW)
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))


def first_step(e):
    global temp_recta
    global temp_rectn
    global rcta
    global rctn
    global comp
    global are_a

    are_a = e

    for r in range(0, comp * 2):
        temp_recta.append(rectangle_values[r].get())
    for i in range(len(temp_recta)):
        t = int(temp_recta[i])
        rcta.append(t)
    for r in range(0, comp):
        temp_rectn.append(rectangle_number[r].get())
    for i in range(len(temp_rectn)):
        t = int(temp_rectn[i])
        rctn.append(t)  
    cal_culate()


window = tk.Tk()
window.configure(background='white')



ws = window.winfo_screenwidth()
hs = window.winfo_screenheight()
w = 980  # width for the Tk root
h = 600  # height for the Tk root
x = (ws / 2) - (w / 2)
y = (hs / 2) - (h / 2)



window.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
canvas = tk.Canvas(window, bg="white", width=980, height=580, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
canvas_scroll = tk.Scrollbar(canvas, command=canvas.yview)
canvas_scroll.place(relx=1, rely=0, relheight=1, anchor=tk.NE)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=canvas_scroll.set, scrollregion=())



l0 = tk.Label(canvas, text="강재 NESTING 최적화 프로그램", font= "calibri 32 bold",fg="royalblue4",bg="white" )
canvas.create_window(200,70, window=l0, anchor=tk.NW)

l00 = tk.Label(canvas, text="제조사 시트 입력 정보", font= "calibri 14 bold", bg="white" )
canvas.create_window(30,155, window=l00, anchor=tk.NW)

photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/sel/Desktop/posco.png")
canvas.create_image(800,10, image=photo, anchor=tk.NW)


line = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/sel/Desktop/line.png")
canvas.create_image(0,130, image=line, anchor=tk.NW)


poscoimg1 = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/sel/Desktop/poscoimg1.png")
canvas.create_image(500,180, image=poscoimg1, anchor=tk.NW)

poscoimg2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="C:/Users/sel/Desktop/poscoimg2.png")
canvas.create_image(0,340, image=poscoimg2, anchor=tk.NW)

l1 = tk.Label(canvas, text="MIN", font= "calibri 14", bg="white")
canvas.create_window(210,180, window=l1, anchor=tk.NW)


l2 = tk.Label(canvas, text="MAX", font= "calibri 14", bg="white")
canvas.create_window(340,180, window=l2, anchor=tk.NW)


l3 = tk.Label(canvas, text="Sheet 폭(SW)", font= "calibri 13", bg="white")
canvas.create_window(33,200, window=l3, anchor=tk.NW)

minw_var = tk.DoubleVar()
entry_minw_number = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=minw_var)
canvas.create_window(220,215, window=entry_minw_number)

maxw_var = tk.DoubleVar()
entry_maxw_number = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=maxw_var)
canvas.create_window(355,215, window=entry_maxw_number)

l4 = tk.Label(canvas, text="Sheet 높이(SH)", font= "calibri 13", bg="white")
canvas.create_window(33,230, window=l4, anchor=tk.NW)

minl_var = tk.DoubleVar()
entry_minl_number = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=minl_var)
canvas.create_window(220,240, window=entry_minl_number)

maxl_var = tk.DoubleVar()
entry_maxl_number = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=maxl_var)
canvas.create_window(355,240, window=entry_maxl_number)

l5 = tk.Label(canvas, text="소요 Component 개수", font= "calibri 13", bg="white")
canvas.create_window(33,260, window=l5, anchor=tk.NW)

rect_var = tk.IntVar()
entry_rect_number = tk.Entry(canvas, textvariable=rect_var)
canvas.create_window(290,270, window=entry_rect_number)

submit_button = tk.Button(canvas, text="Submit",font= "calibri 13", command=lambda: open_window(rect_var.get(),\
                minw_var.get(), maxw_var.get(),minl_var.get(),maxl_var.get()))
canvas.create_window(200, 290, window=submit_button, anchor=tk.NW)
canvas.bind_all('<MouseWheel>', lambda event: canvas.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units"))

def cal_culate():
    print(minw,maxw,minl,maxl,comp,are_a)

window.title("Rectangle Configuration")
window.mainloop()
```

I just tried to print the numbers that are given as input to check if the code is going well. but I got this error.

**Error**

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\sel\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1705, in >**call**
>
> return self.func(*args)
>
> File "", line 92, in 
>     proceed_button = tk.Button(canvas, text="Run",font= "calibri 13", >command=lambda: first_step(area_var.get()))
>
> File "", line 113, in first_step
>      temp_rectn.append(rectangle_number[r].get())
>
> IndexError: list index out of range'

I dont  know where I went wrong.

Comment: Your `rectangle_number` list is empty

Answer (score 2):

int() can't convert empty strings into integers, what you want, is to check if temp_recta[i] is in fact a non-empty string, then try to parse it. If it's an empty string then maybe parse it as 0 (this part will depend largely on your business logic)

```py
>>> s = ''
>>> i = int(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
>>> i = int(s) if s else 0
```

In the above example, if s is '30' i will be 30 and if it's ''(blank string) i will be 0

Comment: This is Look Before You Leap (LBYL). You should instead use an exception handler to just try convert to an int and then handle that appropriately

Comment: I tried and now I am getting this error. IndexError: list index out of range'

Comment: @DevinMaharjan You have the part that fills `rectangle_number` commented out, so it is an empty list. Also, completely changing your question after you have gotten an answer is not the right thing to do since it invalidates the existing answer. See [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266767/3714930).